# Convergence in $L^1$ of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $(Z_n)_{n\geq 1}=X_n^B$.

where $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of random independent variables with density

$$f_n(t)=(n+1)t^n\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(t), \quad \forall n\geq 1$$

and $B$ is a uniform discrete random variable on $\{1,-1\}$, independent from $(X_n)_n$.

I've already proved that $Z_n\longrightarrow^d Z\equiv 1$ when $n\to +\infty$.

Now, I have to establish if $(Z_n)_n$ converges in $L^1$.

To do this, I have to check if

$$\lim_n \mathbb{E}(|Z_n-1|)=0$$

I've calculated the expectation and then I've done the limit. I've found that:

$\mathbb{E}(|Z_n-1|)=\mathbb{E}(|X_n^B-1|)=$

$=\mathbb{E}(|X_n-1| | B=1)\mathbb{P}(B=1)+\mathbb{E}(|X_n^{-1}-1| | B=-1)\mathbb{P}(B=-1)=$

Using the independence between $B$ and $(X_n)_n$ and the fact that $t\in (0,1)$:

$=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(|X_n-1|)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(|X_n^{-1}-1|)=$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(t-1)(n+1)t^n\ dt +\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{t}-1\right)(n+1)t^n\ dt=$

$=\frac{1}{2}\left[(n+1)\left(\frac{t^{n+2}}{n+2}-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)_0^1 + (n+1)\left(\frac{t^{n}}{n}-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)_0^1 \right]= $

$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}+\frac{n+1}{n}-2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$

So, if I consider $n\to +\infty$, that sequence converges clearly to $0$ and so $Z_n\longrightarrow^{L^1}Z\equiv 1$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes! Except when evaluating $|_{0}^{1}$ where I get: $$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Further simplifying my result, I obtain $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$, What doesn't convince you about my calculation?

Comment: Sorry, it's all good! In the previous comment I should have put $-\frac{1}{n+2}$ as you have obtained as well. Seems perfect to me then!